# AngularJS 1.XX - Why would anybody use the "M" restriction for a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know that a angular directive can be define in four ways:

```
'A' - only matches attribute name
'E' - only matches element name
'C' - only matches class name
'M' - only matches comment
```

For example a directive with the restiction "M":

```
angular.module('exampleApp', [])
   .directive('myDirective', function() {
      return {
         restrict: 'M',
         ...
      };
});
```

and declaring the directive in `HTML`

```
<!-- directive: my-directive -->
```

But why would anybody use the `M` restriction for a directive? I find this really strange. Because if i comment out code, i don't want it to run. So why is this a thing?

Comment: If you would at the app source code on your browser you'll see that angular uses comments as directive instructions all the time, so why should they not allow us to use this too?
(yes, it is strange)

Comment: @str hmmm in the current documentation i still see the M restriction, https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Maybe it's a good point to insert javascript only directives, like keyboard controls, mouse controls, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> Best Practice: Prefer using directives via tag name and attributes
>   over comment and class names. Doing so generally makes it easier to
>   determine what directives a given element matches.
>
> Best Practice: Comment directives were commonly used in places where the DOM API limits the ability to create directives that spanned multiple elements
>   (e.g. inside  elements). AngularJS 1.2 introduces
>   ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end as a better solution to this
>   problem. Developers are encouraged to use this over custom comment
>   directives when possible.

It is not good practice to use it now.

According to this [post](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/directive-restrictions) it is used usually only for backwards compatibility and for passing markup validations.

An example of how to use it is below

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('exampleApp', [])
    .directive("comment", function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'M',
        replace : true,
        template : "<h1>Made by a comment directive!</h1>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log(attrs.comment);
        }
      };
    })
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='exampleApp'>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

<body>
  <!-- directive: comment comment argument string -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Because if i comment out code, i don't want it to run.

This is not HTML you're talking about, it's an *Angular* convention/feature. The comment is still visible/accessible inside the DOM as a comment node. The HTML parser won't do anything with it, true. But Angular can still find and parse and act on it. So, yes, it's another way to declare a directive which doesn't have any side effect on the DOM. You have to very explicitly use the `directive: ...` syntax inside a comment; you probably won't be triggering this by accident with code you simply want to comment out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you give me a scenario when i would use "M" instead of the other ways of declaring the directive?

Comment: I've never used it myself for any purpose, but I suppose it's handy when you encounter a situation where it's useful. Again, the advantage is that it doesn't place any impactful element in the DOM; this may be useful when you want a directive which can interact with the DOM (e.g. interact with event bubbling), but should have no visible element.